# How to not load style.css in a specific template

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress I have created a child theme and for some template made changes according to design in style.css in child theme.

I have also created a new template in child theme but I want that the style.css which in child theme not added with the only one template on frontend. my template file name is `template-custom.php`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_dequeue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) function to remove css on specific template

Try below code it will work :

```
/**
 * Remove specific style sheets.
 */
function some_remove_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'yourtemplate.php' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'some-style' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'some-other-style' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'some_remove_styles', 99 );
```